# Capacitor Preferences not seeing UserDefaults key value pairs set with Xcode Launch Arguments

Tags: xcode, capacitor

Capacitor IOS application can't find keys set with Xcode launch arguments.
It can find other keys set using Preferences.set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your launch argument with `CapacitorStorage`.
E.g., `CapacitorStorage.yourKey` value